# How to update Angular2 new router querystring parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my component, I have a  google map. If a user changes the center of the map, I would change my URL and add the new center lat-long in the URL so users can send it as a link. Something like this:
http://myurl.com/map?center=lat!long

I use the new router of RC1

Answer (score 2):

the correct syntax now should be

```
this._router.navigate(['.'], {
            queryParams: { center: this.variable },
            relativeTo: this._route
        });
```

[Doc at Angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

#### Routes

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'map/:id', component: mapComponent }]; //id is optional
```

#### Navigate the route

```
this.router.navigate(['map', '1', { 'center': 'taiwan'  }]);
```

And the uri will be like this :

```
http://localhost:4200/map/1;center=taiwan
```

#### Map component

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
export class mapComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }    
    ngOnInit() {
        //Get route parameter
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            let custIdValue = params['id'];
            let centerValue = params['center'];
            //Do somthing...
        });
    }
}
```

Reference : [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
this.router.navigate( [
  'CurrentPage', { id: 'companyId', param1: 'value1'
}]);
```